# How to clear screen at previous point in python 2 program creating snake game?

Tags: python, linux, python-2.7

I want create a snake game. My first objective is to create an asterisk which can move from top to bottom without pressing any key, simulating the snake 'moving'. What should I add in my code so that `*` moves in the console without printing the number of times loop runs.

My code so far is:

```
import time   
i=0
while (i<5):
    print "*"
    time.sleep(0.5)
    i+=1
```

Comment: You may be able to do it with Python's [`curses`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/curses.html#module-curses) module.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What I would absolutely suggest is to use the `curses` module for fine-grain control over the terminal. You can find many examples of Snake programmed using this module, such as [this one](https://gist.github.com/sanchitgangwar/2158089).

To approach it without curses, I've written some sample code below.
Note that you can't use `print` as-is, because it outputs a newline character `\n` after every call. (In Python 3, you can write `print("hello",end="",flush=True)` to get around this). So, in lei of print, I'm using `sys.stdout.write()`.

Remember to use `Ctrl+C` to end a running Terminal program.

```
import time
from sys import stdout as s

# Let's break this function down:
# After writing a line to stdout, any additional
# writing will happen at the end of this line.
# Use \r (the carriage return) to reset to the beginning of
# the line. Add 40 spaces to clear any characters on that line.
# Then, go back to the beginning of the line again.
def clear():
    s.write("\r" + " "*40 + "\r")

x = 0
x_max = 20

while True:
    clear()
    time.sleep(0.2)

    # Move the snake (*****) by increasing spaces
    s.write(" "*x+"*****")

    # Calling write puts characters into a 'buffer'
    # Calling flush() will write that buffer to the screen
    s.flush()

    x += 1 # Increase the x position

    # If the snake moves too far right,
    # reset him
    if (x > x_max):
        x = 0
```

Comment: Daniel why you have not used s.flush in clear() function as you also used s.write in the function. bit confused about s.flush.

Comment: Every time you called `write`, it prints text onto an 'internal screen'. When you call `flush`, it draws that internal screen to the actual screen. That is, everything is in memory until you call `flush()`, and then it gets drawn to the screen. You *could* put it in `clear()`, but if you did, it would probably make the snake character flash on (`write("*****")`) and off (`clear()`), on, and off. Leaving it in once per loop updates the snake's position without showing the user a completely cleared screen.

Comment: Another way of looking at it is: every time you call `print("my text")`, you're *actually* calling `sys.stdout.write("my text\n"); sys.stdout.flush()`.